# Find nearest neighbor in graph with multiple start nodes?

Tags: graph, nearest-neighbor

i have a weighted graph that represents cities(nodes) and thier distances(weights) on a map. I want to mark two or more cities and get the city that is most in the middle of both. There might be more than one city between this middle city and the marked city but it should be the shortest path for both marked cities. Kind of the nearest neighbor from two nodes.

I searched for graph algroithms like dijkstra and geodesic graphs but i don't know how i could use those to do this task. Am i missing an important algorithm for this?

(My graph contains some node-objects with a list of edge-object each. The edge contains a float as the weight)

Comment: How many nodes do you have? How many edges? Does the graph change much over time?

Comment: Oh there are about 1000 nodes an 2500 edges. The graph can also change... I also wonder how for example google maps performs these algorithms for all the millions cities on the world in a small time. But that is a different thing... :D